# How to structure and write exchangable calculation models (in python3 modules)?

Tags: python, numpy, modules

I do research and compare different numeric models to each other. Therefore, I want to easily switch out the numeric models in my simulations and evaluation code.

Some models work in cartesian coordinates, some in cylindrical coordinates. Some don't have a z-coordinate (yet), since they are primarily two-dimensional; some do. Also, the dimensions and orientations of the input and output vectors need to be the same. Obviously, all those differences need to be alleviated. But how do I structure this best? I find it hard to do the change before I understand how the modules would best look like.

Here are two models:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import kn, iv

# Physics Constants
MU_0 = 4 * np.pi * 1e-7

# Cable Constants
P = 1.862  # length of cable [m] after which we have 360 turn; "Schlaglänge der Leiterwindung"
# A = 2.67e-2  # helix radius [m] = 2*A/sqrt(3) # Helgolandkabel
A = 65e-3  # helix radius [m] = 2*A/sqrt(3)   # 60kV Kabelstück
Q = 2 * np.pi * A / P

# Constants for the measurement
AMPS = 4  # peak current [A] of I * sin(omega * t)
R_inner = 139.2e-3  # in m
R_outer = 127.1e-2  # in m

# Program Constants
SIZE = 12
SIZE_Z = 37
ORDER = 5  # ORDER of bessel functions considered
FRAMES = 60


# coordinate transformation from cylindrical to cartesian coordinates
def coordinate_transform_cy2ca(r, theta, z):
    x = np.cos(theta) * r
    y = np.sin(theta) * r
    return x, y, z


# coordinate transformation back
def coordinate_transform_ca2cy(x, y, z):
    r = np.sqrt(np.square(x) + np.square(y))
    theta = np.arctan2(x, y)
    return r, theta, z


# vector transformation from cylindrical to cartesian coordinate system
def vector_transform_cy2ca(v_r, v_theta, v_z, R, T, Z):
    x = v_r * np.cos(T) - R * np.sin(T) * v_theta
    y = v_r * np.sin(T) + R * np.cos(T) * v_theta
    return x, y, v_z


# vector transformation back
def vector_transform_ca2cy(v_x, v_y, v_z, X, Y, Z):
    sq_devisor = np.square(X) + np.square(Y)
    devisor = np.sqrt(sq_devisor)
    r = v_x * X / devisor + v_y * Y / devisor
    theta = v_x * (-Y / sq_devisor) + v_y * X / sq_devisor
    return r, theta, v_z


# calculate vector component r of the magnetic field in cylinder coordinates
def calc_b_r(R, T, Z, m, current):  # equation 35
    m_1 = m
    m_0 = m - 1
    m_2 = m + 1

    eta_m = np.abs(m_1 * Q)
    eta_r_a = eta_m * R / A

    m_0_term = iv(m_0, eta_m) * kn(m_0, eta_r_a)
    m_2_term = iv(m_2, eta_m) * kn(m_2, eta_r_a)
    m_02_sum = m_0_term + m_2_term

    m_1_term = 2 * m_1 * iv(m_1, eta_m) * kn(m_1, eta_r_a)

    exp_term = np.exp((0 + 1j) * m_1 * (T - 2 * np.pi * Z / P))
    exp_product = 2 * np.pi * R * m_1 * Q / P * exp_term
    bessel_term = m_1_term + exp_product * m_02_sum

    b_r = ((0 + 1j) * 3 * MU_0 * current / (4 * np.pi * R)) * bessel_term
    return b_r


# calculate vector component Theta of the magnetic field in cylinder coordinates
def calc_b_theta(R, T, Z, m, current):
    m_1 = m
    m_0 = m - 1
    m_2 = m + 1

    eta_m = np.abs(m_1 * Q)
    eta_r_a = eta_m * R / A
    exp_term = np.exp((0 + 1j) * m_1 * (T - 2 * np.pi * Z / P))

    m_0_term = iv(m_0, eta_m) * kn(m_0, eta_r_a)
    m_2_term = iv(m_2, eta_m) * kn(m_2, eta_r_a)
    first_term = (2 * np.pi * m_1 * Q / P) * (m_0_term - m_2_term)

    mixed_term = (2 * eta_m / A) * iv(m_1, eta_m) * (kn(m_0, eta_r_a) + m_1 * kn(m_1, eta_r_a) / eta_r_a)
    second_term = mixed_term * exp_term

    bessel_term = second_term - first_term
    b_theta = (3 * MU_0 * current / (4 * np.pi)) * bessel_term
    return b_theta


# calculate vector component z of the magnetic field in cylinder coordinates
def calc_b_z(R, T, Z, m, current):
    m_1 = m
    m_0 = m - 1
    m__1 = m - 2  # the subscript "_1" is supposed to indicate A "-1"  -  its the K_ m-2  in the paper
    m_2 = m + 1

    eta_m = np.abs(m_1 * Q)
    eta_r_a = eta_m * R / A
    exp_term = np.exp((0 + 1j) * m_1 * (T - 2 * np.pi * Z / P))

    m__1_term = (eta_m / A) * iv(m_0, eta_m) * (m_1 * kn(m_0, eta_r_a) / eta_r_a + kn(m__1, eta_r_a))
    # same term as before, just two orders up
    mirror_term = (eta_m / A) * iv(m_2, eta_m) * (m_1 * kn(m_2, eta_r_a) / eta_r_a + kn(m_1, eta_r_a))

    m_0_term = iv(m_0, eta_m) * kn(m_0, eta_r_a) / R
    # same as before, just two orders up
    m_2_term = iv(m_2, eta_m) * kn(m_2, eta_r_a) / R

    m_02_term = (iv(m_0, eta_m) * kn(m_0, eta_r_a) - iv(m_2, eta_m) * kn(m_2, eta_r_a)) * m_1 / R

    bessel_term = m_0_term + m__1_term - m__1_term - mirror_term - m_02_term
    b_z = 3 * MU_0 * Q * current / (4 * np.pi) * bessel_term * exp_term
    return b_z


def main():
    r = np.arange(R_inner, R_outer, (R_outer - R_inner) / 1)  # SIZE)
    theta = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi / SIZE)
    z = np.arange(0, P, P / SIZE_Z)

    R, T, Z = np.meshgrid(r, theta, z)

    # these are the orders of the bessel functions
    # m is the index of the bessel funktion. ms is the list of indices
    ms = np.arange(int(-ORDER / 3) * 3 - 2, ORDER, 3)
    m_num = len(ms)

    # create the

    result_b_r = np.zeros([FRAMES, R.shape[0], R.shape[1], R.shape[2]]).astype(np.complex_)
    result_b_theta = np.zeros([FRAMES, T.shape[0], T.shape[1], T.shape[2]]).astype(np.complex_)
    result_b_z = np.zeros([FRAMES, Z.shape[0], Z.shape[1], Z.shape[2]]).astype(np.complex_)

    for frame in range(FRAMES):
        print(frame)

        #################### here the magnetic field for one time step for all the points in the mesh is calculated
        current = AMPS * np.exp(1j * frame * 2 * np.pi / FRAMES)
        b_r = np.zeros([m_num, R.shape[0], R.shape[1], R.shape[2]]).astype(np.complex_)
        b_theta = np.zeros([m_num, T.shape[0], T.shape[1], T.shape[2]]).astype(np.complex_)
        b_z = np.zeros([m_num, Z.shape[0], Z.shape[1], Z.shape[2]]).astype(np.complex_)

        # iterate over the indices of the bessel function, add them up later
        for i, m in enumerate(ms):
            b_r[i] = calc_b_r(R, T, Z, m, current)
            b_theta[i] = calc_b_theta(R, T, Z, m, current)
            b_z[i] = calc_b_z(R, T, Z, m, current)

        # this adds up the different parts resulting from the different orders of the bessel functions
        result_b_r[frame] = np.sum(b_r, axis=0)
        result_b_theta[frame] = np.sum(b_theta, axis=0)
        result_b_z[frame] = np.sum(b_z, axis=0)
    ##################### now the calculation for one point in time for all the indices of the bessel functions is complete

    # coordinate transform cylindrical to cartesian coordinates
    b_x, b_y, b_z = vector_transform_cy2ca(result_b_r, result_b_theta, result_b_z, R, T, Z)
    X, Y, Z = coordinate_transform_cy2ca(R, T, Z)

    # combine field vectors into one matrix
    result_b = np.array([b_x, b_y, b_z])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is a model in 2D.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc
from typing import List, Pattern, Union, Tuple

# rc('text', usetex=True)
CURRENT_PEAK = 4.0
MU_0 = 4 * np.pi * 1e-7
CONDUCTOR_DISTANCE = 0.065
HELIX_RADIUS = CONDUCTOR_DISTANCE / np.sqrt(3)
LENGTH_OF_LAY = 1.862
Q = 2 * np.pi * HELIX_RADIUS / LENGTH_OF_LAY  # this expresses the cable specific relation between length of lay and
# conductor distance. for parallel conductors it is infinit, for strongly twisted ones it is small. It is A metric
# for how much magnetic field can leave the cable.


POINTS: np.ndarray = np.array(
    [[7.0, 0], [13.7, 0], [20.2, 0], [27.7, 0], [37, 0], [44.1, 0], [51.5, 0], [61.2, 0], [72, 0], [84.9, 0], [97, 0],
     [117.1, 0]]) * 1e-2
POINTS += np.array([10.0, 0.0]) * 1e-2  # radius of the pipe
DIPOL_POINT = np.array([0, 0])




def magnetic_dipol_field_in_point(dipol_coordinates, dipol_vector, point_coordinates):
    direction_vector = (point_coordinates - dipol_coordinates)
    direction_unit_vector = (direction_vector.T / np.linalg.norm(direction_vector, axis=1).T).T
    #    print(np.linalg.norm(direction_vector, axis=1))
    dot = dipol_vector.T * direction_unit_vector
    r = np.linalg.norm(direction_vector, axis=1)
    zähler = (3 * direction_unit_vector * dot - dipol_vector).T  # * ( np.exp(-Q*.089*r) / 1.55)
    nenner = np.power(np.linalg.norm(direction_vector, axis=1), 2.0)
    b_vector = (MU_0 / (4 * np.pi)) * zähler / nenner
    return b_vector.T


def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=2.3, facecolor="none", linewidth=2, edgecolor='lightblue', alpha=0.3,
                        label=r"outer diameter of cable")
    plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

    dipol_vectors = np.array([1, 0])
    dipol_vectors = dipol_vectors / np.linalg.norm(dipol_vectors, axis=0)
    # print("dipol_vectors: ",dipol_vectors)
    dipol_vectors = dipol_vectors * CURRENT_PEAK * (CONDUCTOR_DISTANCE * np.sqrt(3) / 2) * 2

    #    res = np.zeros_like(POINTS)
    res = magnetic_dipol_field_in_point(DIPOL_POINT.T, dipol_vectors, POINTS)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to learn how to refactor this code into interchangeable modules. I have more models, this is just to illustrate the mess I am coming from, and I look for examples to follow, to unify my codebase.

Comment: This won't run. You haven't defined `DIPOL_POINT` and `POINTS`.

Comment: yes, i was cleaning up the code before posting it, and destroyed it while doing so. i need to update the code. - done

Comment: This is fairly opaque to me. Can you add a description matching up corresponding elements in your two models, and where they exist in the code?

Comment: I'm with Reinderien, I started writing an answer, but we'd need a little bit more detail. I understand scientific code is usually a mess ahah, but if you could also clarify what are the inputs and outputs of the code, I believe we could come up with something

Comment: @IEatBagels, I hear you, and I reworked the first module yesterday and started on the second one. The second one is harder because it is 2D (and needs to be 3D). My challenge is that I need to rethink it, and that takes time. I hope to update the second module today or tomorrow. It gets a lot clearer right away from doing so, and the parallel structures become more visible. If I knew how to pause and unpause a question, I would do so, but I will ping you guys once I am done as a crutch.